# How should I index my table to get the fastest return on SELECT?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-5.5

If I have a table with 4 columns `a,b,c,d` that will be used in searching for rows.

```
id        (PK)      BIGINT
a                   TINYINT
b                   CHAR
c                   VARCHAR 
d                   BIGINT
e                   VARCHAR
f                   VARCHAR
g                   VARCHAR
.
. 
.
```

And my queries will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a = 1 AND b = 'com') AND c = '1A2X31423'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a = 2 AND b = 'edu') AND d = '1A2X31423'
```

In my database, `a` and `b` are going to create the subset of items I want to search within, and `c` and `d` are the items within that subset that I want to find.

What is the best way to set up my indexes? Should a and b be setup as a composite index, and then c and d have their own? Any advice and reasoning would be helpful.

Additional Info: There are currently about 20 million rows, and the table is 30 columns wide.

Comment: Please, show your `explain` result

Comment: First I would try composite indexes `(a, b, c)` and `(a, b, d)`

Comment: @imran, I haven't built this schema out yet, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: You may have perfectly valid reasons for a 30 column wide table, but such width *can* be indicative of poor design.